# Service Principal with Contributor role cannot access the resource and cannot see the resource with &quot;az resource list&quot;

Tags: azure, permissions, devops, roles

I have an Azure subscription with ACR and App Configuration services.

I am implementing a pipeline that access Azure through DevOps Service Connection that has Contributor role for both resources. However, using Az Client task pipeline cannot see or access those resources.

If I execute "az resources list" I don't see those resources even though Service Connection has access to them.

I have the same setup working on my personal subscription. What am I missing?

Tried to reproduce same scenario in my personal subscription and it worked with the same level of access for Service Connection.
Also it works in PowerShell console with a user account with the same permissions.

Comment: Have you tried `az account set --subscription <name or id>` for the subscription where your resources are?

Comment: Yes Az CLI task in pipeline execute "az account set" after "az login"